# Testing for mutually exclusive correct assertions

Tags: java, testing, junit

I have a loop in my code which goes over a set of strings. Said strings are then passed along to several other functions.

In my tests, I'm basically emulating the flow of code and asserting at the start of each method I expect it to visit, if the string is correct.

But I can only write the test method once. Meaning that I have to do the following to catch all the different strings:

```
assertTrue(string.equals("test1") || string.equals("test2") || string.equals("test3") || ...);
```

However, there's a problem with this if one or more of those strings are not successfully passed to the list that is looped over. Since this is a chain of OR statements, it will succeed as long as there is 1 correct string, regardless of whether any of the other strings are missing. Which is a problem.

I can't emulate the loop, I can only emulate the functions receiving the data each time.

Is there a way to deal with this problem?

EDIT: some clarification.

I start out with a list of strings.

This list gets looped over, meaning every single string instance will go through a bunch of functions. And then the next string. And so on.

In the test, I can write dummies for the methods the string goes through. This means I override the behavior of the actual code and send my own custom return. This has to be correct though, since the function following that has to properly process what I just send to it.

But, when I start the test with the dummy data, it will do the loop, meaning the same function gets called multiple times, each time with a different string. I can't just do 1 test for one of the strings, because the next loop will fail on the next string.

Comment: You could for example store the result of each `string.equals(anotherString)` in a boolean, and then `assertTrue(myBoolean1 && myBoolean2 && ...)`?

Comment: Can you give more details please on what is the expected behaviour? Why do you say you can only write the test method once? Why not have a test method per case? For verifying your set of strings contains all the ones you have as an OR clause, why not create a collection of your test list of strings and then loop over the list, to asserts each string in the list is in that collection?